# time.Duration is unexpectedly 'divided' by 1'000'000

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm using `time.Duration` to store data in a struct as follows:

```
type ApiAccessToken struct {
    ...
    ExpiredIn   *time.Duration `bson:"expired_in,omitempty" json:"expired_in,omitempty"`
    ...
}
```

and I set it using a constant like this:

```
...
const ApiAccessTokenDefaultExpiresIn = 7 * 24 * time.Hour
...
d := ApiAccessTokenDefaultExpiresIn
data := &ApiAccessToken{
    ...
    ExpiredIn: &d
    ...
}
...
```

then I use `mgo` to insert the data to database.

I did checking after creating the `data` instance and before inserting the data and the value of `ExpiredIn` was 604'800'000'000'000 but in MongoDB it became 604'800'000 (or `NumberLong(604800000)`).

Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: you must have exceeded it's max
I suggest using int64 instead

Comment: @danicheeta time.Duration is int64, NumberLong is also int64

Comment: Is Mongo automatically converting to seconds?

Comment: @Flimzy not sure, it can be, that _may_ explain it. But if I start multiplying the value with `time.Second` and `mgo`/MongoDB decides to store the whole nanosecond I'm going to have a _very long-lived_ token.

Comment: *in MongoDB it became 604'800'000* But does it have the correct value when you unmarshal it back into a `time.Duration`?

Comment: What does the marshalled bson look like?

Comment: Before saving to database it has the correct value `604'800'000'000'000` but then when I read it from database it becomes `604'800'000` (using both `mgo` and robo3t). Maybe it's `mgo` truncating the value to second instead of nanosecond?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>Current solution: multiply the returned `ExpiredIn` from MongoDB with `time.Second` so I got my Go-flavoured nanosecond `time.Duration`.</strike>

I ended up using the `string` representation of `time.Duration` because it simply works.

I created two functions for my `ApiAccessToken` struct that does the job of writing/reading the data.

```
func (tok *ApiAccessToken) SetExpiredIn(t time.Duration) {
    s := t.String() // read the string
    tok.ExpiredIn = &s
}

func (tok *ApiAccessToken) GetExpiredIn() (r bool, t time.Duration) {
    if tok.ExpiredIn != nil {
        var err error
        t, err = time.ParseDuration(*tok.ExpiredIn) // parse the string
        r = (err == nil)                            // can we use this?
    }
    return
}
```

And voila, it works!

[image: string]

Answer (score 2):

We would normally write custom MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON for specific types to control what happens to their values before/after marshaling/unmarshaling.

```
type ExpiredIn struct {
    time.Duration
}

func (e *ExpiredIn) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(string(e.Nanoseconds())), nil
}

func (e *ExpiredIn) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(string(data[:])), 10, 64)
    e.Duration = time.Duration(i)
    return nil

}
```

Here's the test code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

type Token struct {
    ExpiredIn time.Duration
}

type ExpiredIn struct {
    time.Duration
}

func (e *ExpiredIn) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(string(e.Nanoseconds())), nil
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("test").C("tokens")
    err = c.Insert(&Recipe{7 * 24 * time.Hour})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And you're done!

[image]

Comment: Hmm, interesting... but why won't `mgo` (or the marshaller) just read `time.Duration` as is? Does the marshaller default to read `ExpiredIn.Seconds()`?

Comment: Don't know it could be implemented using type switch.

Comment: I've just tried the solution but it's not working...

I basically just copied the `ExpiredIn` struct declaration and the functions. The `MarshalJSON` is not even called! How do I actually apply this to my existing struct?

Comment: what's your MongoDB version?

Comment: The shell says `3.2.11`

Comment: Mine is v3.6.3. I think It could be a incompatibility.